# Can't make work Chrome extension passing message

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

this is my scenario: I click on my extension, background cycles all tabs, put them in an array and send it to content, content searches for a specific id in the page, if it's included in one of the tabs' titles, it sends an email with some data, otherwise it sends a message to background. It opens a new tab, cycles again all tabs and sends back the tabs array to content so it can check again the titles and send email.

I'm new on Chrome extension, I can't make this message passing work

Manifest.json (manifest v3)

```
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "scripting",
    "tabGroups",
    "tabs",
    "storage"
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "options_ui": {
    "page": "options.html",
    "open_in_tab": false
  }
```

Background.js

```
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {

  let allTabs = [];

  try {
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tab) {
      for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i = i + 1) {
        allTabs.push(tab[i]);
      }
    });
  }
  catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }

  chrome.scripting.executeScript({
    target: { tabId: tab.id },
    files: ['content.js']
  });

  chrome.tabs.query({ currentWindow: true, active: true }, function (tabs) {
    port = chrome.tabs.connect(tabs[0].id, { name: "emailrelease" });
    port.postMessage({ tabs: allTabs });
  });

});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(
  function (port) {
    port.onMessage.addListener(
      function (request) {
        if (request.action === "update") {

          chrome.tabs.create({
            url: request.link,
            selected: false,
            active: false
          });

          let allTabs = [];
          try {
            chrome.tabs.query({}, function (tab) {
              for (i = 0; i < tab.length; i = i + 1) {
                allTabs.push(tab[i]);
              }
              port.postMessage({ tabs: allTabs });
            });
          }
          catch (err) {
            console.log(err);
          }
        }
        return true;
      });
  });
```

Content.js

```
const port = chrome.runtime.connect({ name: "emailrelease" });
port.onMessage.addListener(
  function (request) {
    let qa = "";
    let qaTitle = "";
    let buildUrl = "";

    let tabs = request.tabs;
    console.log("tabs", tabs);
    let desc = document.getElementById("MainPane").innerHTML;
    let i = desc.indexOf("$id");
    if (i > 0) {
      i += 18;
      let n = desc.indexOf("<", i);
      qa = desc.substring(i, n);
    }

    if (qa && tabs) {
      for (let i = 0; i < tabs.length; i++) {
        let element = tabs[i];

        if (element.title.search(qa) > 0)
          qaTitle = element.title;

        if (element.active)
          buildUrl = element.url;
      }
    }

    if (qaTitle == "") {

      port.postMessage({ 
        action: "update",
        link: "https://website" + qa
      });
    }

    //------- mail ----------------------
    //code for email
  }
);
```

I appreciate any help
Thanks

Comment: You mentioned sending messages, but I don't see any code that would be doing that in your scripts. The right way to send messages to a content script is to run ```chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, {
    'message': 'execute_links'
})``` from background.js. In your content script, you'll need ```chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.message == 'execute_links') {
        // do thing
    }
})```. Also, be aware you need to reload each web page after reloading the extension or the messages won't be received.

Comment: Thaks for reply. What do you mean I need to reload each web pageafter reloading the extension?

Comment: You need to refresh* the page. Chrome breaks the message path between content scripts and background.js when your extension is updated. So, you need to refresh the page to insert the new content script to re-open the path to background.js

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample of communication between background and tab.

manifest.json

```json
{
  "name": "content_scripts + background",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ],
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_title": "hoge"
  }
}
```

background.js

```js
chrome.action.onClicked.addListener((tab) => {
  console.log("Send");
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, "message", (response) => {
    console.log("Recv response = " + response.title);
  });
});
```

matches.js

```js
console.log("matches.js");

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((message, sender, sendResponse) => {
  console.log("Recv. Send response = " + document.title);
  sendResponse({ title: document.title });

  return true;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. In my background I need to send a message at the beginning with an array, if in content I can't find what I need, it sends a message to background that fill again the array and send a new message back to content
How can I send 2 messages from background, one at beginning and one if there are conditions?